# When does 'System.ExecutionEngineException' ocurs?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm developing on asp.net using infragistics controls.
I have develop a web page where it uses heavy functionalities of the webdatagrid and it loaded very slow.

I have tested the page many times but somehow it started to fire this exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Without displaying any source control.
My question is , what is this error means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In some cases, an application that targets the .NET Framework may throw an ExecutionEngineException exception during garbage collection when an application or the system on which it is running is under a heavy load. In this case, To work around this issue, you can disable concurrent garbage collection by modifying the application's configuration file. For more information, see How to: Disable Concurrent Garbage Collection.

Check this link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.executionengineexception.aspx